# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to make a "QA" version of an app. It's running fine on the iPhone on the prod version. However, after I copy the build, the exact same code that works for the prod version fails on the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
```

Here's the offending code:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL;
    if ([defaultPlistName isEqualToString:@"DefaultConfig"]) 
    {
        modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TabBarTest" withExtension:@"mom"];
    }
    else 
    {
        modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:databaseName withExtension:@"momd"];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",databaseName);
    NSLog(@"%@", [modelURL absoluteString]);
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

This code is pulling in the same database, but for some reason, it's not finding it in the QA version. I have checked out a lot of the solutions on SO, but I'm not really getting anywhere. Note that it's always  "DefaultConfig", so it's always trying to load the "TabBarTest" database. Somehow, it seems as if it finds it in the prod's bundle, but not the QA bundle. Is there something I should be doing to initialize it somehow?